# Python : Call by Reference

Tags: python

I'm new to python. Can anyone help me to understand the call by reference in python.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void rd(float *a, int *n)
{
    int i;
    for (i=1;i<= *n;i++) {
        printf("Enter element %d: ",
               i); scanf("%f", &a[i]);
    }
}

float sum(float *a, int *n)
{
    int i; float s=0;
    for (i=1 ; i <= *n ; i++) s = s +
                                  a[i]; return s;
}

int main(void)
{
    int size; float *x, g;
    printf("Give size of array: "); scanf("%d", &size);
    x = (float *)malloc(size*sizeof(float)); // dynamic memory allocation
    printf("\n");
    rd(x, &size); // passing the addresses
    g = sum(x, &size); // passing the addresses
    printf("\nSum of elements = %f\n", g);
    printf("\nDONE ! Hit any key ...");
    getch(); return 0;
}
```

This is C example i trying to solve in python. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Python does not support call by reference semantics. But it's hardly necessary here.

Comment: Python's data model is quite different to C's, and the concept of call by reference doesn't really map well to Python. You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python there is no way to pass "the address" of a "place" (a variable, an array element, a dictionary value or an instance member).

The only way to provide other code the ability to change a place is to provide a "path" to reach it (e.g. the variable name, the array and the index and so on). As a very strange alternative (not used often in Python) you can pass a "writer" function that will change the place... for example:

```
def func(a, b, placeWriter):
    placeWriter(a + b)

def caller():
    mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    def writer(x):
        mylist[3] = x
    func(10, 20, writer)
```

Much more common instead is writing functions that simply return the needed values; note that in Python returning multiple values is trivial while in C this is not supported and passing addresses is used instead:

```
def func():             # void f(int *a, int *b, int *c) {
    return 1, 2, 3      #     *a=1; *b=2; *c=3;
                        # }

def caller():           # void caller() { int a, b, c;
    a, b, c = func()    #     func(&a, &b, &c);
    ...
```